# A single word for an immigrant from a different part of the same country

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word for '*immigrant*' here, that specifically refers to people from a different part of the same country.

"As the capital city, X has a very large *immigrant* population".

I feel that *immigrant* in this sentence could be understood to mean immigrants from outside the country.

Comment: intra-national migrations, intra-national migrant?

Comment: You could try **migrant**, but it does not necessarily mean from within the same country.

Comment: "Transient" seems too temporary (also synonymous with "hobo") and "transplant" makes it seem somehow involuntary. "Out-of-towner"? This is a tough one. There really ought to be a word, too, because it describes the population of many cities.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to say, but at what point does a new resident become part of the "non-immigrant" population?

Comment: The capital city is largely populated by people that *relocated* from the surrounding area.

Comment: @Lambie, that's exactly what I mean, but I don't think that it flows very well in writing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have heard the word "transplant" used to describe people who are living in a place or city that they did not grow up in.

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/transplant):

> ## transplant
>
> /ˈtræn(t)splænt/
>
> noun
>
> A person or thing that has been moved to a new place or situation.
>
> *The Gang actually was a band of Florida transplants who moved north for bigger purses.*

Comment: In the US, this is not usually used but it can be used. But it has a different meaning. It is not a general term, sociologically speaking.

Comment: @Lambie maybe this is a regional thing? I live in the Boston area and I hear this term used all the time, especially because there are so many people here who fit the definition. I asked a co-worker from Vermont for his thoughts and he thought it was a very strange word choice to use to describe a human person!

Comment: @user266420 Well, maybe we're neighbors. It can be used but isn't a sociology term, which is what I thought the OP wanted. However, it's fine if not.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to them as ***new residents***. Sample usage:

> For the second straight year, Florida registered the top migration rate of any state, with about 16 ***new residents*** per 1,000 population. After slowing somewhat during the recession, migration has picked back up as more retirees establish residency in the Sunshine State.
>   <sub>[Where Are Americans Moving? According to New Census Data, Utah.](http://www.governing.com/topics/urban/gov-where-americans-moving-2016-state-migration-estimates.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Depending where they are from you could call them:

- northerners, southerners, westerners or easterlings
- country folk
- bushies
- provincials
- rurals
- itinerants